# Cannot find Hyper-V option in Windows (10 Home) feature turn on/off for enabling VT-x to install emulator accelerator (HAXM)

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-10, hyper-v, haxm

I am trying to run a simple hello world application in Android studio. While running it gave this error "cannot launch AVD in emulator... requires hardware acceleration. Please ensure intel HAXM is properly installed and usable".
So, I downloaded Intel x86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer), then went to Android->sdk->extras->intel->hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and executed intelHAXM_android.exe. During its execution I encountered the error " VT-x in not turned on".
1. While doing a bit research on this, I encountered this solution:
 Control panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Turn windows features on or off,
it displayed a list of features but I couldn't find Hyper-V option. How can I enable it, in order to run my application ?
2. I have also tried running the bcdedit command, then also it gave the same error "cannot launch AVD in emulator... requires hardware acceleration. Please ensure intel HAXM is properly installed and usable".
I am using Windows 10 Home. How should I enable it? Also I read somewhere that Windows 10 Home does not have Hyper-V feature then what is the alternative to run my application?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your windows 32 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V or Virtualization Technology is something that your processor supports. I had similar problem when i was trying to set up Android Studio. It is rather easy to solve the problem, you have to open your bios menu(when starting up your PC pressing F11 or something different according to your BIOS) then you will navigate and find Intel® Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT) and enable it. By default it is disabled.

After this install Intel HAXM and you are good to go.

Answer (score 5):

Hyper-V is not supported on Windows 10 Home edition ([Microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility)).

> The Hyper-V role can be enabled on these versions of Windows 10:
>
> - Windows 10 Enterprise
> - Windows 10 Professional
> - Windows 10 Education
>
> The Hyper-V role cannot be installed on:
>
> - Windows 10 Home
> - Windows 10 Mobile
> - Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise