# Can't deploy my "Hello World" app in Xamarin (Visual Studio)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

After I downloaded Xamarin I first had this problem:
`Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`

After reading this post, [java Lang UnsupportedClassVersion Error in Xamarin Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457947/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion-error-in-xamarin-studio), I installed JDK 1.8.0_101 (Windows, 32-bit) and *that* problem no longer appears.

However, I still can't build my first app (I choose "New Project" -> "Android" -> "Blank App".

I deleted "Android SDK Build-tools" 24.0 and installed 24.0.1 (as recommended from the post)
[image]

Xamarin options in Visual Studio:
[image]

Output using "Build":

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App11, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  App11 -> C:\Users\Jefecito\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\App11\App11\bin\Debug\App11.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
2>Starting deploy Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
2>Starting emulator Android_Accelerated_x86 ...
2>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
2>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Output using "Xamarin Diagnostics":

```
[I:]:                     Tracking android devices started
[D:]:                     TrackDeviceTask got: 
[I:]:                     Got new device list from adb with 0 devices
[D:]:                     Tracking avd started
[D:]:                     avd watcher *.ini path: 'C:\Users\Jefecito\.android\avd'
[D:]:                     avd watcher android path: 'C:\Users\Jefecito\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\android.bat'
[D:]:                     avd watcher: got device list from avd with 2 devices
```

I can deploy to two "devices" but none of them works:

- Android_Accelerated_x86 (Android 6.0 API 23)
- Android_ARmv7a (Android
  6.0 API 23)

I have no idea why I can't deploy a blank app in Xamarin. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the full build output? Please send us your respective build logs: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs (XS) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

Comment: @JonDouglas I enabled Intel Virtual Technology from BIOS and after that it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some helper from the previous answers I solved this problem by activiating Intel Virtual Technology from BIOS.

I couldn't find Hyper-V on my machine as explained here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install

According to post https://stackoverflow.com/a/36171914/2524586 you might need to install Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) but that wasn't necessary for me or I already have it installed without knowing it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you start the Android Emulator manually via Visual Studio Emulator for Android? If not, please post the Messages.
I had a lot of Problem in the past 2 weeks to get that Emulator up and running. Finaly it was a Problem with Hyper-V and my installed Kaspersky Internet Security. I had to uninstall Kaspersky - then Hyper-V worked fine again and so did the Android Emulator.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried deploying to a real device? Seems to be an issue with the emulator